# Write enum with String to parcel

Tags: java, android, enums, parcelable

I had Parcelable enum like this:

```
 public enum Option implements Parcelable {

    DATA_BASE, TRIPS, BIG_PHOTOS,
    OLD_PHOTOS, FILTERS_IMAGES,
    CATEGORIES_IMAGES, PAGES,
    SOUNDS, PUBLIC_TRANSPORT, MAPS;        

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Option> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Option>() {

        public Option createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return Option.values()[in.readInt()];
        }

        public Option[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Option[size];
        }

    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(ordinal());
    }
}
```

Now I modified it and it looks like:

```
 public enum Option implements Parcelable {

    DATA_BASE("Database"), TRIPS("Trips"), BIG_PHOTOS("BigPhotos"),
    OLD_PHOTOS("OldPhotos"), FILTERS_IMAGES("FiltersImages"),
    CATEGORIES_IMAGES("CategoriesImages"), PAGES("Pages"),
    SOUNDS("Sounds"), PUBLIC_TRANSPORT("PublicTransport"), MAPS("Maps");

    private String option;

    Option(String option){
        this.option = option;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return option;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Option> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Option>() {

        public Option createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            //...
        }

        public Option[] newArray(int size) {
            //...
        }

    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        //...
    }
}
```

How should I implement writeToParcel(), createFromParcel() and newArray() int this Enum? I need that to pass it through extra in intent.

Comment: Certainly do not use ordinal() to persist it somewhere. If you ever change the order or insert/delete an Enum member, you data will be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by:

```
public enum Option implements Parcelable {

    DATA_BASE("Database"), TRIPS("Trips"), BIG_PHOTOS("BigPhotos"),
    OLD_PHOTOS("OldPhotos"), FILTERS_IMAGES("FiltersImages"),
    CATEGORIES_IMAGES("CategoriesImages"), PAGES("Pages"),
    SOUNDS("Sounds"), PUBLIC_TRANSPORT("PublicTransport"), MAPS("Maps");

    private String option;

    Option(String option){
        this.option = option;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return option;
    }

    private void setOption(String option){
        this.option = option;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Option> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Option>() {

        public Option createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            Option option = Option.values()[in.readInt()];
            option.setOption(in.readString());
            return option;
        }

        public Option[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Option[size];
        }

    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(ordinal());
        out.writeString(option);
    }
}
```

Comment: Putting a setter on an enum is the worst possible solution to this problem. It completely removes all the advantages of using an enum

Answer (score 36):

This is an old question but there is a better solution:

```
dest.writeString(myEnumOption.name());
```

and

```
myEnumOption = MyEnum.valueOf(in.readString());
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be late for the OP, but it may help others, so I'll still post this.

1. As it was mentioned before, it's a bad practice to have a setter to an enum's member. If you need that member, make it **final** (which excludes the possibility of a setter for it)
2. You don't need to save that member (in your case the String 'option') into the Parcel and restore it on recreation.

My implementation would be as follows

```
public enum Option implements Parcelable {

    DATA_BASE("Database"), TRIPS("Trips"), BIG_PHOTOS("BigPhotos"),
    OLD_PHOTOS("OldPhotos"), FILTERS_IMAGES("FiltersImages"),
    CATEGORIES_IMAGES("CategoriesImages"), PAGES("Pages"),
    SOUNDS("Sounds"), PUBLIC_TRANSPORT("PublicTransport"), MAPS("Maps");

    private final String option;

    Option(String option){
        this.option = option;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return option;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Option> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Option>() {

        public Option createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return values()[in.readInt()];
        }

        public Option[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Option[size];
        }

    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(ordinal());
    }

}
```

Comment: The only thing to note with using an Ordinal, is if entries are inserted or reordered then any previously saved values will be broken. Refactoring poses a similar issue when using Name like I do, but is less likely to be broken by an accidental change (eg. automatic code organisation)

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason you're making your enum `Parcelable` is to pass it in an `Intent`, you don't need to to that. enums are `Serializable`, so you can pass it like:

```
intent.putExtra("EnumValue", Option.DATA_BASE);
```

and retrieve it using:

```
Option myEnum = (Option) intent.getSerializableExtra("EnumValue");
```

Comment: I'm passing it as List<Option> so I need.

Comment: If you're using one of the standard List implementations (like ArrayList or LinkedList for example) then these are `Serializable`. If your list is `Serializable` and your content is `Serializable` (as yours is) then you can still use this method. It just depends if the implementation of `List` you're using is `Serializable`.  You'd just need to put the list in the call to `intent.putExtra()` and when you get it out, cast it to the list of Option.