# Is it worth to implement parcelable on a simple enum

Tags: android

I know that enums implement serializable interface and that parcelable is much faster. 
The question is, is it worth to implement parcelable on an enum to gain speed or are they fast enough even with serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your enum Parcelable [like this answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25263703/845128), but it's really not worth it unless you actually determined this to be a bottleneck for you.  He has to hack his way around it by parceling the ordinal value and his enum value which can be very messy with little benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you would need to worry about this. Enums are used to represent a fixed set of constants (more info here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). You would parcel an object in order to maintain an objects state by essentially breaking down the object into its primitive components in one activity and reconstruct the object in another activity.  (more info here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). But since enums are constants, there's no varying state to the enum to worry about on the other side. As long as the enum exists in your parcelable class, it will be there for free on the other side.

Recovering the state of your **variables** on the other side is the important part of parceling.